# Securely Erase NVME SSD that is connected via USB Converter

Tags: usb, ssd, security, formatting, secure-erase

Is there a way to securely erase a NVME SSD that is connected via a USB converter?

Normally I use parted magic to format an SSD, the M.2 SATA SSDs can be easily connected via a converter into a 2.5" sata connector, which then can be securely erased.

With M.2 however the easiest adapter is an USB Adapter. Though parted magic is not able to then securely erase it.

Comment: It's unlikeky that any enclosure would implement translation for `sanitize` or `format`.

Comment: Better use an PCIe adapter card (M.2 to PCIe x4 slot). Those cards are also cheap as they are passive, e.g. Icy Box IB-PCI208.